# subset std::map into std::vector<std::map> of predefined length

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmap

I'm trying to subset a `std::map<string,string>` into a vector of maps, each with predefined length + rest. I'm trying to follow the solution found at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66448686/can-a-stdmap-be-efficiently-split-into-two-stdmaps-at-an-iterator). The problem here is that I don't want to split the map into two parts, but into `n` parts each of equal size + rest. This is how im trying to achieve this (not compiling because of a nullptr):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main(){
using namespace std::string_literals;

    auto code = std::map<std::string, std::string>{
        {"Red"s, "Red"s},
        {"Blue"s, "Blue"s},
        {"Green"s, "Green"s},
        {"Fuchsia"s, "Fuchsia"s},
        {"Mauve"s, "Mauve"s},
        { "Gamboge"s, "Gamboge"s },
        {"Vermillion"s, "Vermillion"s}
    };
    
    std::vector<std::map<std::string,std::string>> subsetCode;
    auto it = code.begin();
    auto bt = code.begin();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < code.size(); i += 2)
        {
            auto last = std::min(code.size(), i + 2);
            
            std::advance(it, last);
            std::advance(bt, last-2);
            subsetCode.push_back(std::map{
                std::make_move_iterator(bt),
                std::make_move_iterator(it)});
        }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < subsetCode.size(); i++) {
        for (auto [key, value]: subsetCode[i]){
            std::cout << key << ":" << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I think I am stuck with moving the iterator for the lower bound.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: This program is virtually guaranteed to have an index out of bounds. At some point, `last` will be `code.size()`, and then `std::advance(it, last);` would run out of bounds since `it` is likely not `code.begin()` at that time; it's already been advanced. You keep advancing `it` and `bt` by an ever-increasing offset, which is probably not what you wanted. Perhaps you meant to reset them to `code.begin()` on every iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO “the rest” is poorly defined, because (e.g.) splitting 20 elements into 11 parts would yield 10 parts with 1 element each and a “rest” with 10 elements, which is (sort of) ugly if the splitting should be uniform. I would instead use 9 parts with 2 elements in each and then 2 “rests” with 1 element in each. But that’s just a (early) side note; you can tweak this all you like.

The important part is probably the iterator. Well, because you are removing elements from and inserting elements into the same type of `map`, your best bet is `extract()` and its counterpart, the overload of `insert()` that takes nodes. The beauty of this is that the type(s) you use in the `map` do **not** need to support move-semantics at all in this case; the entire node remains in existence and therefore nothing needs to be moved. No `move_iterator` is involved here either — that would **only** matter if we dereferenced the iterator, which we don’t do.

First let’s define the `map` splitting (node transfer) for *any* `map`-like type and for *any* `vector`-like type, simply because we can:

```cpp
template<template<typename ... S> class R,
         template<typename ... A> class C,
         typename I,
         typename ... S, typename ... A>
void
transfer_segments(C<A...> &source, I &it,
                  size_t n_segs, const size_t seg_size,
                  R<C<A...>, S...> &sink) {
  for (; n_segs; --n_segs) {
    auto &seg{sink.emplace_back()};
    for (size_t i{0}; i < seg_size; ++i)
      seg.insert(source.extract(it++));
  }
}

template<template<typename ... S> class R,
         template<typename ... A> class C,
         typename ... S, typename ... A>
void
split_container(C<A...> &&source, const size_t n_segs,
                R<C<A...>, S...> &sink) {
  const size_t seg_leftover{source.size() % n_segs};
  const size_t seg_size{source.size() / n_segs};
  auto it{source.begin()};
  transfer_segments(source, it, seg_leftover, seg_size + 1, sink);
  transfer_segments(source, it, n_segs - seg_leftover, seg_size, sink);
}
```

These templates could gain (much needed) extra type-safety using C++20 concepts, but this is omitted for the sake of brevity. Next we can test the solution on your data and types:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace { /* ... magic templates from above go here ... */ }

int main() {
  static const auto get_map{
    []() -> std::map<std::string, std::string> {
      using namespace std::string_literals;
      return {{"Red"s, "Red"s},
              {"Blue"s, "Blue"s},
              {"Green"s, "Green"s},
              {"Fuchsia"s, "Fuchsia"s},
              {"Mauve"s, "Mauve"s},
              {"Gamboge"s, "Gamboge"s},
              {"Vermillion"s, "Vermillion"s}};
    }};

  for (size_t n_segs{1}; n_segs <= 7; ++n_segs) {
    std::cout << n_segs << ": {\n";
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> segs;
    split_container(get_map(), n_segs, segs);
    for (const auto &seg : segs) {
      std::cout << "     (";
      for (const auto &[k, v] : seg)
        std::cout << " [" << k << ':' << v << ']';
      std::cout << " )\n";
    }
    std::cout << "   }\n";
  }
}
```

And the output is:

```
1: {
     ( [Blue:Blue] [Fuchsia:Fuchsia] [Gamboge:Gamboge] [Green:Green] [Mauve:Mauve] [Red:Red] [Vermillion:Vermillion] )
   }
2: {
     ( [Blue:Blue] [Fuchsia:Fuchsia] [Gamboge:Gamboge] [Green:Green] )
     ( [Mauve:Mauve] [Red:Red] [Vermillion:Vermillion] )
   }
3: {
     ( [Blue:Blue] [Fuchsia:Fuchsia] [Gamboge:Gamboge] )
     ( [Green:Green] [Mauve:Mauve] )
     ( [Red:Red] [Vermillion:Vermillion] )
   }
4: {
     ( [Blue:Blue] [Fuchsia:Fuchsia] )
     ( [Gamboge:Gamboge] [Green:Green] )
     ( [Mauve:Mauve] [Red:Red] )
     ( [Vermillion:Vermillion] )
   }
5: {
     ( [Blue:Blue] [Fuchsia:Fuchsia] )
     ( [Gamboge:Gamboge] [Green:Green] )
     ( [Mauve:Mauve] )
     ( [Red:Red] )
     ( [Vermillion:Vermillion] )
   }
6: {
     ( [Blue:Blue] [Fuchsia:Fuchsia] )
     ( [Gamboge:Gamboge] )
     ( [Green:Green] )
     ( [Mauve:Mauve] )
     ( [Red:Red] )
     ( [Vermillion:Vermillion] )
   }
7: {
     ( [Blue:Blue] )
     ( [Fuchsia:Fuchsia] )
     ( [Gamboge:Gamboge] )
     ( [Green:Green] )
     ( [Mauve:Mauve] )
     ( [Red:Red] )
     ( [Vermillion:Vermillion] )
   }
```

When it comes to a different kind of splitting into uniform parts and “the rest”, the algorithm can be easily adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to subset the map to n parts, the sub map's size equal map.size()/n, hear is a o(n) solution:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

int main() {
    auto code = std::map<std::string, std::string>{
        {"Red", "Red"},
        {"Blue", "Blue"},
        {"Green", "Green"},
        {"Fuchsia", "Fuchsia"},
        {"Mauve", "Mauve"},
        { "Gamboge", "Gamboge" },
        {"Vermillion", "Vermillion"}
    };
    
    // assume you want each part size is 2.
    constexpr int subSize = 2; 

    std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> subsetCodes;    
    std::map<std::string, std::string> subset;
    for (auto& item : code) {
        subset.insert({item.first, std::move(item.second)});
        while (subset.size() == subSize) {
            subsetCodes.push_back(std::move(subset));
            subset = std::map<std::string, std::string>();
        }
    }
    if (!subset.empty())
      subsetCodes.push_back(std::move(subset));
    code.clear();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < subsetCodes.size(); i++) {
        for (auto [key, value]: subsetCodes[i]){
            std::cout << key << ":" << value << " ";
        }
        std::cout << " " << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is *not* O(n). (`std::map` is a red/black tree.)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek you are right